# JAVA Plug n' Play Implementations

Tags: java, dependency-injection, wildfly-10

Let's consider I have the following  interface

```
public interface Hello {
    String hello();
}
```

and I have N implementations each one in a separated jar, eg.:

-- english.jar

```
public class EnglishHello implements Hello {

   public String hello(){
       return "Hello";
   }
}
```

-- portuguese.jar

```
public class PortugueseHello implements Hello {

    public String hello(){
        return "Olá";
    }
}
```

I want to :

1 - Just drop the jar on Wildfly deployment folder
2 - It register itself or something like this 
3 - When I call an webservice like "***localhost:8080/app/hello?lang=EN"***, It locates the implementation and answer "Hello" on the the Language requested.

Something like OSGI? CDI?

Hope it makes sense, and sorry if this is a duplicated question, I didn't know how to search for this matter.

Comment: Simple WAR wit webapp would do...

Comment: I don't need to deploy an web service,  I need to choose between implementations on the fly

Comment: Is it is only about language, then use resource bundle like everybody does - after all it is made for i18n.

Comment: No,  the Language is just an example,  I don't want to apply internatiolization